# generate ws client with wsdl and axis2

Tags: eclipse, wsdl, jax-ws, apache-axis

I have this wsdl

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.7-hudson-48-. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.7-hudson-48-. -->
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.consulta.spcjava.spcbrasil.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://webservice.consulta.spcjava.spcbrasil.org/" name="consultaWebService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://webservice.consulta.spcjava.spcbrasil.org/" schemaLocation="https://servicos.spc.org.br:443/spc/remoting/ws/consulta/consultaWebService?xsd=1" />
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="consultar">
<part name="filtro" element="tns:filtro" />
</message>
<message name="consultarResponse">
<part name="resultado" element="tns:resultado" />
</message>
<message name="listarProdutos" />
<message name="listarProdutosResponse">
<part name="produtos" element="tns:produtos" />
</message>
<message name="detalharProduto">
<part name="codigo-produto" element="tns:codigo-produto" />
</message>
<message name="detalharProdutoResponse">
<part name="produto" element="tns:produto" />
</message>
<portType name="consultaWebService">
<operation name="consultar">
<input message="tns:consultar" />
<output message="tns:consultarResponse" />
</operation>
<operation name="listarProdutos">
<input message="tns:listarProdutos" />
<output message="tns:listarProdutosResponse" />
</operation>
<operation name="detalharProduto">
<input message="tns:detalharProduto" />
<output message="tns:detalharProdutoResponse" />
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="consultaWebServicePortBinding" type="tns:consultaWebService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
<operation name="consultar">
<soap:operation soapAction="" />
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="listarProdutos">
<soap:operation soapAction="" />
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="detalharProduto">
<soap:operation soapAction="" />
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="consultaWebService">
<port name="consultaWebServicePort" binding="tns:consultaWebServicePortBinding">
<soap:address location="https://servicos.spc.org.br:443/spc/remoting/ws/consulta/consultaWebService" />
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

When I generate the wsdl with axis2 appears the error

> Exception occurred during code generation for WSDL  : org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: WSDLException (at /definitions/types/xsd:schema): faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error occurred trying to resolve schema referenced at 'https://servicos.spc.org.br:443/spc/remoting/ws/consulta/consultaWebService?xsd=1', relative to 'file:/C:/Users/Tiago Roque/workspace/spe/WebContent/WEB-INF/ws/consultaWebService.xml.wsdl'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://servicos.spc.org.br:443/spc/remoting/ws/consulta/consultaWebService?xsd=1

I use eclipse for generate
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wsdl references an external xml-schema (see `xsd:import`) which is access protected. This is why you get the 401 (UNAUTHORIZED) error ( `https://servicos.spc.org.br:443/spc/remoting/ws/consulta/consultaWebService?xsd=1`).

Probably you can request an inlined version of the wsdl (where all schema definitions are inlined in one complete wsdl).

Comment: when I use netbeans and try without the axis2 on the way:
new \ client to webservice \ Local File
Appears User and password to be entered and generates the client but not in axis2 format.
the axis2 in eclipse should show User and password too?

Comment: according to the current axis documentation this might not be implemented (at least I couldn't find anything about it).
But since you are dealing with HTTP basic authentication you could pass the credentials within the URL: `https://user:secretpassword@example.com/path/to/wsdl`

Comment: See that strange, in my work I have the June version of eclipse and today I managed to generate, appeared User wsdl and password and generated the webservice client. I think the problem is with the Luna version of Eclipse that I installed in my home.

Comment: Tanks fateddy for your help